# How am I putting in an variabel into blade from PHP file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to make a simple "forgot password" function, so everything works but I don't know how to put in my variabel into blade file.

Here's my source:

```
public function postForgot(Request $request) {

    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|min:3',

    ]);

    if (User::where('email', '=', $request->input('email'))->exists()) {

        // user found

        Mail::send('emails.forgot', function($message) {

            $message->to($_POST['email'],$_POST['email'])->subject('We almost got your password back...');

        });

    } else {

        echo "Not found user";

    }

}
```

Route file:

```
    Route::get('/forgot/new_password', [
    'uses' => '\Zyllox\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getForgotNewPassword',

]);

Route::post('/forgot/new_password', [
    'uses' => '\Zyllox\Http\Controllers\AuthController@postForgotNewPassword',
    'as' => 'auth.new_pass',
    'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);
```

Here's my simple blade file:

```
Here's your token m8 : {{ $token }}
```

I want the $token variable to work inside the blade file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your token into the template data array in the `Mail::send()` function (second parameter).

```
public function postForgot(Request $request) {
    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|min:3',
    ]);
    if (User::where('email', '=', $request->input('email'))->exists()) {
        Mail::send('emails.forgot',['token' => $token], function($message) {
            $message->to($_POST['email'],$_POST['email'])->subject('We almost got your password back...');
        });
    } else {
        echo "Not found user";
    }
}
```